# Error: bad runtime process port [''] on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm developing a site with GAE and webapp2. Occasionally while running my development server, I get the following error out of nowhere, with no stack trace:

`http_runtime.py:404] bad runtime process port ['']`

Sometimes this happens when I change part of my database schema (it's still early in development) and the problem is fixed if I restart the server and clear the datastore. However sometimes it happens for seemingly no reason.

The solution is always to just restart the server, but I feel weird not knowing why I'm getting this error. Is this something that just happens when the server has been up for too long? Is there anything I can do to prevent it? Does this happen in production? I want to know before I start thinking about deploying.

Comment: I have been developing on appengine since 2008 and never seen this.  What is your runtime environment - OS, python etc.. any specific things you are using like modules, backends, search, sockets, channels ?

Comment: I'm on OSX v10.7, Python v2.7, GoogleAppEngineLauncher v1.8.3 and I've been viewing the page in Chrome v29. I haven't been using any features besides the datastore and urlfetch, and I haven't been using Django or any framework besides webapp2.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not sure about the exact mechanism, from the log trace and looking at http_runtime.py, I believe that goapp and devappserver communicate over stdin and stdout, probably using a pipe like mechanism. http_runtime::start() parses args to acquire the port to be used to run the server. If any of the strings in args contain {port}, it replaces that substring with the selected port. This allows a user-specified runtime to pass the port along to the subprocess as a command-line argument.

Using fmt.PrintXXX() in init() seems to break this by modifying the contents of Stdout. This particular error is thrown at line 391, and is due to http_runtime getting a ValueError exception while trying to convert the port argument to an int.

Please check if you are using fmt.PrintXXX() in init. Please switch to writing to stderr, or better yet use the log interface. This is what worked for me.

You can check this google groups link(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/v_6-qY0-dD8) for more details.

Comment: Please avoid link only posts - describe the solution inside your answer.

Comment: @MaciejLach: Have tried my best to explain the error. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For reference the error is coming from this line of code:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/http_runtime.py

It is in the start() function so maybe something is causing your dev_app_server to restart itself and it is trying to reuse a port that is not available anymore?

Can you try to enable debugging with devappserver and see if you can reproduce it and paste in the context?

`dev_appserver.py --dev_appserver_log_level=debug` sets the log output to debug level.

From `dev_appserver.py --help`

Comment: I set the flag, thinking I probably wouldn't see the error for a while. Immediately after restarting, I got it (without even sending any requests) and there was no debug log. I restarted again and it hasn't happened since.

Comment: I forgot an = between log_level and debug.  Did that change things?  You can add --logs_path=LOGS_FILE if you want to save the logs to a file instead of stderr|stdout.

Comment: actually it's '--dev_appserver_log_level=debug'

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today. The error was consistent, i.e. restart did not help.

In my case, the problem seemed to be related to virtualenv. The essence of what I had done was this:

```
#In myproject/src/main which is the GAE project folder
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install lxml
cd ../..
dev_appserver src/main
```

Note that the GAE root was in src/main but I was running from the "grandparent directory" which is my git repository root.

When instead set up the same virtualenv in the grandparent directory, the problem disappeared. I.e.

```
#In myproject/ which is my git repository root
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install lxml
dev_appserver src/main
```

I do not know why this makes a difference.